# How can I sort by number when I have letters in front?

Tags: excel, sorting, filter, excel-formula

I have a a list with some names of some products...
Usually the names are something like this IR123456 or AR123456... if I'll sort them I'll have all the names that contain AR ahead that the ones with IR. The problem is that this are pairs of produts and I want them one below another... something like
AR123456
IR123456
AR123457
IR123457 instead of AR123456
AR123457
IR123456
IR123457
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose the names are in the A column. Create a sort column (in this example on B column). In the sort column use only the numbers.

```
Product     Sort
AR123456    =MID(A2,3,100)
IR123456    (drag or copy the formula above)
...         ...
IR123457    (drag or copy the formula above)
```

Then sort on the B column.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Simple solution that just does it's job!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the substitute function (nested) to replace any non numeric characters with an empty string "" and this will leave you with the numberic part

```
A1 = "abc dog"
A2=SUBSTITUTE(A1,"a","") 
contents "bc dog"
```

which you can then sort against

Answer (score 0):

One way is to extract the substring out of each string where the substring contains only numerical part. maintain an associative array (key=>value) to store the the numerical part and the actual string. Sort the array based on the numerical part (either based on key or based on value) and u'll get the original string sorted :)

Comment: thanks but I'm trying to do this in Excel and I guess it's not that easy as you describe it...